# Can we play video on browserfield of blackberry

Tags: blackberry

i get video url from webservice. Can we play the video on browserfield?

```
 BrowserField bf = new BrowserField();
     bf.requestContent(url);
     add(bf);
```

When i execute in simulator. The video image display and follow a error occur that "Access violation reading from 0x00000004".

Can i check on device.? its affect any problem on my device from this error.? Pls help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you cannot access the video from the browser field,this is my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

You need to pay it through the built-in browser which automatically opens the built-in video player. Call it like this: `Browser.getDefaultSession().displayPage(url);`

Comment: k than k. First i execute as you tell as. The browser screen has been shown, after that the video has played.   browser screen not required. thats so i asked. Any relevant code to play video on media player . Do u have..

Comment: please edit your question to reflect that you don't need the browser; now your question will be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1448666/video-streaming-on-blackberry -- I posted there and answer for you just now!

Comment: hi i use the code you given. its working fine for small size mp4. but when i pass large size mp4 url, it play 15 seconds  . after, a black screen displayed.

Comment: if it works, please mark the answer as the solution; and about the large mp4, you are using the built-in player, so if you want to customize it, then roll your own by using RIM apis

Answer (score 0):

Just pass the video url straightly in the browser. It automatically opens the default video player and it plays the video..

Comment: k. thank u.  os 7 simulator not loading on my system. my system os is windows server 2008. My friend  system os is windows xp. it is working on that system.  Any solution? my question posted below link. if u know pls help.,        http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7292318/blakcberry-os-7-simulator-not-loading-on-my-system